# Override toString of objects inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have the following array, initialized using `map` and knockout's `fromJS`, as so:

```
self.loadProducts = function (applyBindings) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlGetProducts,
        success: function (data) {
            self.Products($.map(data[0].Value, function (item) { return ko.mapping.fromJS(item) }));
        },
    });
};
```

Now each product contains a property called `Tags`, which I bind on a `span`:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">
    <tr role="row">
        <td><span data-bind="text: Tags"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The result is the `span` will have as text `Tags`' `toString()`, as it is an array, and, by default, the `toString` function is displaying item separated by a comma (`,`). What I want is to override this method, and display them correctly, with a space + comma.

After documentation, I've found out you can use `Obj.prototype.toString` to override it for individual objects, but what when they get auto mapping like in my case? I don't know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `toString` is not the way I'd do it.

I'd implement a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) that returned the desired string.

I.e.in your ViewModel:

```
self.TagsText = ko.computedd(function() {
  // compose text with the contents of the array
  return text;
}, self);
```

Then, change your html to bind the text to this new computed:

```
<span data-bind="text: TagsText">
```

Another advantage of the computed observable is that, if you add or remove items from `Products` (which shuld be an `observableArray`), the text will update.